# how to shift multiple element off the beginning of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array contained 20 keys.

```
$arr = array(
               "1" = "one",
               "2" = "two",
               .
               .
               .
               "20" = "twenty"
            );
```

Now I want to ignore ten key first, and I want this output :

```
print_r($output);

// eleven, twelve, ..., twenty
```

here is one solution. using *[array_shift($arr)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)*, but this solution is not optimized, because I should use 10 time of that function. something like this:

```
$arr = array_shift($arr); // ignoring first key
$arr = array_shift($arr); // ignoring second key
.
.
.
$arr = array_shift($arr); // ignoring tenth key
```

there is any better solution ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this :

```
$array = array_slice($array, 10);
```

for more information, look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

Answer (score 7):

I think you might be looking for [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php), which directly modifies the array (same as `array_shift`), instead of returning a new array.

```
$n = 2;  // number of elements to shift
array_splice($array, 0, $n);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is little similar to you. However, You can also try. See the following example. It would be more comfortable code:

```
$students = array("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "more");
$to_be_shifted = 3;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $to_be_shifted; $i++) {
    array_shift($students);
}
print_r($students);
```

Comment: How is that an improvement to the other answers?

Comment: for little fast access, for...next is used. It can be used instead of writing same code again and again. Is not it?

Comment: Compared to the original question, yes. But it already had an accepted answer from over 8 years ago with only one line of code...